# Edit and search item in listview

Tags: c#, wpf

is there any control like jquery datatable in WPF for searching item from listview or how i can implement efficient search in listvew.
secondly, I have an image and title in listview control. How can I add "edit functionality" to change  image Title. 
I don't have any clue about it because I'm new in WPF. how I can perform this task. any example or useful code will be helpfull for me.

```
<ListView  Name="lvDataBinding">

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView  >
                <GridViewColumn  >

                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>

                        <DataTemplate >
                            <StackPanel Margin="20,5,0,0"  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

                                <Image Margin="15,5,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PopupImageStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Width="60" ToolTip="{Binding Name}" Height="60" Source="{Binding ImgPath}"></Image>
                                <TextBlock Visibility="Hidden" Text="{Binding Name}"/>

                            </StackPanel>

                        </DataTemplate>

                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>

                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn  >

                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>

                        <DataTemplate >
                            <StackPanel Margin="20,5,0,0"  Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">

                                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Title}">
                                    <TextBlock.Style>

                                        <Style>
                                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize"  Value="20"></Setter></Style>
                                    </TextBlock.Style>

                                </TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>

                        </DataTemplate>

                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>

                </GridViewColumn>
                <!--<GridViewColumn   DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />-->
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>



        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">

                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
            </Style>

        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```